# Site permissions relative to library permissions

Tags: permissions

I want to be able to give user John Doe full permissions to a site, but I want to give the same user read-only permissions (or perhaps none at all) to a specific document library that resides within that site.

Is this possible?  If so, how do I go about setting this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of comment discussion, I think we've nailed it down.

Permissions trickle down in Sharepoint.  You have web application permissions in Central Administration (Application Management -> Policy for web application) to deal with that grant permissions to users globally for the web application.

The next set of permissions down would be site collection owner/site collection administrator.  If a user is a SCO/SCA, they'll have access to everything in the site collection whether or not they've been granted permissions.

Then you have site permissions, either by a Sharepoint group or explicitly added.

If you remove John Doe from the web application policy and he is not listed as a SCO/SCA, he will not have access to the document library if his Sharepoint group has been removed from the access list.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the settings on the document library and you should see a link for Permissions.  You can set his permissions there.  You can also set it at the document level if you really want to go that far, but that would not be recommended as it gets hard to maintain security when you have permissions that granular.

Granting/denying permissions to individual users is not really a best practice.  You should create a group called something like "restricted readers" and then set permissions for that group in the list.  This allows you to easily add/remove others who may also have this same restriction down the road without having to figure out all of the places where you have set permissions.

Comment: I've done this, and for some reason granting John Doe full access to the site overrides any permissions listed specifically for the library.  Also, I understand it isn't best practice, but grating individuals explicit permissions is more conducive for the way my site collection is structured.

Comment: Is John Doe listed as a site owner in central admin or has he been added to the site collection administrators in the Site Settings?

Comment: Is this user also in a group that has higher permissions on the same list?  If so, the higher permissions apply.

Comment: @PirateEric - No and no, and yet John Doe can still see a link in the Quick Launch to a library for which he has no permissions, open said library and view the file names, and open documents within said library and edit them.

Comment: @Dave Wise - No, John Doe isn't in a group with higher permissions.

Comment: Does the Authenticated Users meta group have higher permissions on the list?

Comment: @Dave Wise - There are no groups given permissions on the library.  Only five individual user accounts with explicit permission levels.

Comment: Then the library will need to be spun off into it's own subsite or permissions redone at the site level so the user in question doesn't have admin privies.

Comment: @PirateEric - But why is this happening?  If I have to do this with every document library I'm going to have to restructure _huge_ portions of my site collection.

Comment: Try this.  Go to Site Settings on the root of the site in question.  There should be a link worded something like "Check Effective Permissions".  Click on that and enter the user's ID.  That should tell you his actual permissions on the site.  There may be a similar link on the List Settings but I can't recall right now.

Comment: Because the user has full control which is taking presidence over everything else.  It has to be a security measure so that if a user revokes all access to something, the permisions can be reset and modified again.  If you knock the user down to the member group, does he still see the library?

Comment: @Dave Wise - No additional useful information from that.

Comment: @PirateEric - Giving John Doe read-only permissions on the library resulted in no change.

Comment: Does the John Doe actually need Full Control at the root?  If he is not a site owner or site collection admin, then there isn't really a need for this.  Would "design" permissions satisfy the needs?  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288074.aspx

Comment: If giving him read only permission at the root and he still has access means he's listed as a site collection administrator or site owner or there is a web application policy granting him that level of control.  Those people will always be able to see everything regardless of the permissions set.

Comment: @PirateEric, Agreed, but JonnyP already said that wasn't the case.

Comment: There's no other explaination for it if at the root they have read permissions and have been removed from the document library that the user still has access.  It could be a web application policy granting all users read access or something like that.  Application Management -> Policy for web application in central admin.

Comment: @PirateEric - I just checked Policy for Web Application for the site collection and John Doe's account (as well as my own, whoops) were both listed there!  John Doe happens to be a coworker who's out to lunch so I can't have him test his permission level, but I have a good feeling about this.  If this works you should post that comment up as an answer and I'll give you the credit for it.

Comment: @PirateEric - Success!  The child no longer wants to swear!  Post that up as an answer my friend!

Comment: Alternatively Dave could edit his answer to include the information that helped me (Central Administration -> Application Management -> Manage web applications -> Policy for Web Application -> User Policy, remove John Doe from list).  I'll let you guys fight it out.  ;)

Comment: @JonnyP, nah, PirateEric was the one who suggested to check the web application policies, he deserves the credit